# as3 use setter in other class(parent)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a simple setter which i like to access with a child class.
Here is the parent class code :

```
    public class DeGeheimeMissie extends MovieClip
{
    var deLader:URLLoader;
    var deXmlData:XML;
    public var hoofdVragenLijst:Object = new Object(); 
    public var subVragenLijst:Object = new Object(); 
    public var hetAntwoord:String;

    public function DeGeheimeMissie() 
    {
        var hetVerzoek:URLRequest;
        hetVerzoek = new URLRequest("dialogen.xml");
        deLader = new URLLoader(hetVerzoek);
        deLader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, vragenGeladen);
        deLader.load(hetVerzoek);

        instObama.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showVragen);
        instObama.buttonMode    = true;
        instObama.useHandCursor = true;
    }

    public function set hetAntw(str:String):void
    {
        hetAntwoord = str;
    }
```

and here is the child class where i try to access it:

```
public class Rutte extends MovieClip
{
    var deLader:URLLoader;
    var deXmlData:XML;
    public var antwoordenOverzicht = []; 
    //constructor
    public function Rutte()
    {
        var hetVerzoek:URLRequest;
        hetVerzoek = new URLRequest("dialogen.xml");
        deLader = new URLLoader(hetVerzoek);
        deLader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, antwoordenGeladen);
        deLader.load(hetVerzoek);

        instRutte.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showAntwoorden);
        instRutte.buttonMode    = true;
        instRutte.useHandCursor = true;
    }
        public function setAntwoord(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        var antw = e.currentTarget.text.charAt(0);
        trace(e.currentTarget.text.charAt(0));
        this.parent.hetAntw(antw);
    }
```

The error i get here is:
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method hetAntwoord through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

Comment: it should occur to you that using the same name might cause problems ....

Comment: Yea, but i already changed the function name still same problem :<

Comment: you did not change the function name but the static var name and now you are trying to use it as a method. I suggest to start over and check carefully what you are doing then come back when you have a real problem.

Comment: my bad i just changed it here correctly, even tho i made that mistake the error is still the same.

Comment: Show us the whole classes, please. Just eliminate the unnecessary methods. We cannot see too much from what you have showed us here.

Comment: this is obviously a misguided design. If the setter is linked to a static var then the setter should logically be static as well.

Comment: @BotMaster Doesn't matter if i do static or not i still get the same error which isn't solved yet.

Comment: it's not solved because you do not understand what you are doing and what a static method or variable is. You use "this.parent" which is a DisplayObjectContainer type and has no such method obviously. There's no issue to fix here, the only problem is your programming level and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, this is how we use setters :
this.parent.hetAntw = antw;

But why making a public setter on a public static var ?